# Step-down as LED driver leads to flickering

Tags: led, switching, led-driver, step-down

I received a LED driver board that uses an [A6902D](https://dir.heisener.com/DatasheetDownload/A6902D.pdf) step-down as regulator.
Here the schematic of the driver section:

[image]

`PWM_3` is the signal from the MCU: 500 Hz (tried frequencies up to 15 kHz) 0..100% PWM, 5V
`C` is the output signal where the LEDs are connected. It's a series of 6 LEDs with a total forward voltage of about 19V. The power supply is 24V but I tried to lower it down to 20V without any change in the behavior. [Here](https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-14339284/GW%20CSHPM1.PM_EN.pdf) the datasheet of the LED.

The problem is the LED flickering at almost any settings of PWM. Most at lower intensities, but also over 75% you can see the annoying flickering.

Checking with an oscilloscope I see that the input PWM is correct: clean and stable signal, while the output (pin 1) is interrupted here and there. I mean there are fraction of seconds where the A6902D keeps the output low, even if the PWM is still present at the input.

I guess it's a sort of protection, but I'm not able to find out the root cause.
Of course feel free to ask any specific measure I might take to help to better understand what's going on.

Another thing that may be useful. These drivers are very sensitive and burn too often. I destroyed several boards (the A6902D smoked) just keeping those in my hand, even without the LED connected. So I'm afraid there are some caveats in the design.

Comment: Driving the COMP pin with a PWM signal seems at least a bit strange to me. How long does the error amp need to get up and running? What about static operation: Does the converter work as intended when applying 0Hz PWM?

Comment: First time I see it being done like this. The highs of the external PWM are pulling the output of the error amplifier in the A6902D low, so the A6902D can only regulate its output when the external PWM is low, do I understand that correctly?